# How can clone the mercurial repo with all history

Tags: mercurial, bitbucket

I have the server with `mercurial`. Now i have the home computer where i am pushing all my repo to `bitbucket` account.

My `Work serve`r has all the revisions like 900 on them. Now i want to clone that repo with all those `900 revisions` and then `push` them to bitbucket so that i can see all those 900 revisions in my bitbucket account.

Is this possible

Answer (score 3):

In short, yes.  Mercurial is a *distributed* version control system, which means (amongst other things) that every clone contains by default the full repository history. [Bitbucket 101](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Bitbucket+101) is an excellent place to start for the basics, as is [HgInit](http://hginit.com/).

For the clone home and then push method, you would do something like:

```
hg clone ssh://user@workserver/pathtorepo repo
cd repo
hg push ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/username/repo
```

To push to the Bitbucket, you'll need to have public key authentication set up (see Bitbucket 101), for the work server portion, public key authentication is nice, but may not be necessary if the server's policy allows for interactive authentication.

If you don't need a local copy, Bitbucket also offer the option to directly [import](https://bitbucket.org/repo/import) (i.e. clone) from a third party repository. This will almost certainly be faster since the upstream speed on most residential Internet connections is rather slow.